# How can I use Linq to join between objects and entities?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a collection of IDs in memory, and I would like to fetch only rows from a DB matching those IDs.

In SQL, I could either write a query like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1,3,5,10)` or do a join between tables.

My problem is that EF can't build a query where I join my EF-data with my local array or list.

(I'm using EF4.1, but I'm guessing the problem/solution would be similar in older versions, as well as with Linq-to-SQL.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Contains()` with your ID collection `myIDs` to generate the equivalent `WHERE id IN ..` query:

```
var results = context.mytable.Where(x => myIds.Contains(x.Id));
```